# Easiest way to write similarities in two strings to a new dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I have a function that I want to compare two arrays, find matches, then create a third array. The function finds the comparisons, but when I try to return an object, the program aborts. My initial thought is that having different values for c1.numMembers and c2.numMembers might cause my loop to malfunction. Any help is appreciated. Here is what I have.

```
Club mergeClubs(Club& c1, Club& c2)
{
    Club combined;
    combined.clubName = c1.clubName + "/" + c2.clubName;
    string* x = new string[combined.numMembers];
    for(int i = 0;i<c1.numMembers;i++)
    {
        for(int k =0;k<c2.numMembers;k++)
        {
            if(c1.members[i]==c2.members[k])
            {
                x[combined.numMembers] = c1.members[i];
                combined.numMembers++;
            }
        }
    }
    combined.members = x;


    return combined;
}
```

Thanks for all the answers. I understand that using vectors would be simpler, but I am simply not allowed to change anything about the initial class, where members* is a dynamic array that we must use in each Club type.  I changed my code up, and I have it so the final array combined.members has the correct members in it, but I still get an error returning it.  Here is the new code that I have.

```
Club mergeClubs(Club& c1, Club& c2)
{
//I changed the arrays to vectors to sort them and find the duplicates, then wrote     it back into an array. inefficient yes, but using vectors
//in the first place would have made the project 1000000000000x easier.
    Club combined(c1.clubName + "/" + c2.clubName);
    vector<string> x1;
    vector<string> x2;
    vector<string> combine;
    for(int i = 0;i<c1.numMembers;i++)
    {
        x1.push_back(c1.members[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<c2.numMembers;i++)
    {
        x2.push_back(c2.members[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<x1.size();i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j<x2.size();j++)
        {
            if(x1[i]==x2[j])
            {
                combine.push_back(x1[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    for(vector<string>::const_iterator i = combine.begin(); i != combine.end();     ++i)
    combined.numMembers = combine.size();
    combined.members = &combine[0];


    return combined;
 }
```

And trust me, I know how inefficient this is.

Comment: This looks wrong: `string* x = new string[combined.numMembers]`. Has `combined.numMembers` even been initialized? And why not use a vector instead of an array?

Comment: @qlear - if you used `std::vector` and `std::set_intersection` (provided the names are sorted), most of that code you wrote wouldn't be necessary.  I would post it as an answer, but would need to see what is `Club` and `members`.

Comment: Edited my answer for your new code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider using a container for your `members` strings. If you were to use a `std::set` for instance, you could do the following:

```
std::set<std::string> a, b, c;
// assume a and b contain some strings
std::set_intersection(
  a.begin(), a.end(),
  b.begin(), b.end(),
  std::inserter(c, c.end())
);
```

You could also use `vector`s (or another container), you would just have to make sure they have been `sort`ed before you create the intersection.

---

The issue with your new code is that you are assigning `combined.members` to a pointer that will be deleted when the function returns (belonging to `combine`). You still have to create an array of `string`s and copy them from the vector if you want to go this route (presumably you thought of this at some point, but your loop over `container` doesn't seem to serve any purpose).

You can still use the library algorithms on raw pointers, so a better solution to your issue if you cannot change your struct might be something like the following:

Assuming `Club` looks like this

```
struct Club
{
  std::string clubName;
  std::string* members;
  int numMembers;
};

Club mergeClubs(Club& c1, Club& c2)
{
  Club combined{
    c1.clubName + "/" + c2.clubName,
    new std::string[c1.numMembers + c2.numMembers],
    0
  };

  std::sort(c1.members, c1.members + c1.numMembers);
  std::sort(c2.members, c2.members + c2.numMembers); 

  auto end = std::set_intersection(
    c1.members, c1.members + c1.numMembers,
    c2.members, c2.members + c2.numMembers,
    combined.members
  );

  combined.numMembers = end - combined.members;

  return combined;
}
```

---

> And trust me, I know how inefficient this is.

It isn't only about efficiency, I would still choose the code at the top of my answer even if using the standard containers were slower than handling arrays (it generally isn't, especially if you use `vector`s), as it is far easier to write, read, and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you used `combined.numMembers` before it was defined, when you allocated the strings `x`.  Instead of allocating an array of strings, use an expandable container, such as `std::vector<T>`.  Use `std::vector<T>::append` to add each string.  Then at the end, allocate `combined.members` array and copy each string over from the temporary vector.